# Cakephp 1.3 Set/Pass ID to the view

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a table called Policy and a table called Declination. Policy hasMany Declination. Declination belongs to Policy. Now with that said, I am trying to save the ID of a policy in a field called Policy_id in the Declination table. Unfortunately, I'm having no luck. I believe I having trouble with my view. Let me explain what I am doing..in my controller I am reading 1 record and then setting the ID from that array to policy_id. Once I do that I send that variable to the view via set(). Once there I am using that variable in a hidden field. When I run my script there the data saves but the id does not populate. I have been stuck on this over 2 days and can't wrap my head around it! One thing I might add..I am passing the ID from that policy in via the URL. So the url looks something like localhost/site/add/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx. Im not sure if I should grab it from there or not. If I should can you explain or point me somewhere as to where I can learn. If I shouldn't please inform me as to why not. Thanks!

Model

```
 <?php
```

class Declination extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Declination';

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'name' => 'CONCAT(Declination.first_name,\' \',Declination.last_name)'
);

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Policy' => array(
        'className' => 'Policy',
        'foreignKey' => 'policy_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Reason' => array(
        'className' => 'Reason',
        'foreignKey' => 'reason_id'
    ),
    'ContactType' => array(
        'className' => 'ContactType',
        'foreignKey' => 'contact_type_id'
    )
);

public function beforeSave() {
    if (array_key_exists('dated', $this->data[$this->alias]) && !empty($this->data[$this->alias]['dated'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['dated'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->data[$this->alias]['dated']));
    }
    if(array_key_exists('reason_id', $this->data[$this->alias])) {
        if (!$this->Reason->isOther($this->data[$this->alias]['reason_id'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['other'] = null;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Controller

```
class DeclinationsController extends AppController {

public $name = 'Declinations';

/**
 * add function.
 * 
 * @access public
 * @param mixed $id (default: null)
 * @return void
 */
public function add($id = null) {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->loadmodel('Policy');
        $policy = $this->Policy->read('id', $id);
        $policy_id = $policy['Policy']['id'];

        $this->Declination->create();
        if ($this->Declination->saveAll($this->data['Declination'])) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Declinations saved.', true));
            $this->redirect(array(
                'controller' => 'coverages',
                'action' => 'view',
                $id
            ));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Declinations failed to save.', true));
        }
    }

    $reasons = $this->Declination->Reason->find('list');
    $contactTypes = $this->Declination->ContactType->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('id', 'reasons', 'contactTypes', '$policy_id'));
}
```

View

```
    <?php echo $this->Ui->widgetHeader(__('Policy Declinations', true)); ?>
<?php $this->Ui->widgetContent(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->UiForm->create('Declination', array(
        'url' => array(
            'controller' => 'declinations',
            'action' => 'add',
            $id
        )
    )); ?>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++): ?>
        <h4>Declination <?php echo ($i + 1); ?></h4>


        <?php echo $this->UiForm->create("Declination.{$i}.policy_id", array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => '$policy_id')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.first_name"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.last_name"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.company"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.contact_type_id"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.phone_number"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.reason_id"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.other", array(
            'label' => 'If other, please supply a reason'
        )); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.dated", array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'readonly' => 'readonly',
            'data-datepicker' => ''
        )); ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php echo $this->UiForm->end('Continue'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Ui->widgetContentEnd(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I grabbed the $id variable that was in my view and set it as my value. So in stead of my value being $policy_id....it is $id. I also deleted some things out of my controller that I did not need. Please see below. Hope this helps someone!

View

```
    <?php echo $this->Ui->widgetHeader(__('Policy Declinations', true)); ?>
<?php $this->Ui->widgetContent(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->UiForm->create('Declination', array(
        'url' => array(
            'controller' => 'declinations',
            'action' => 'add',
            $id
        )
    )); ?>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++): ?>
        <h4>Declination <?php echo ($i + 1); ?></h4>

        <?php echo $this->UiForm->create('Declination'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.policy_id", array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $id)); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.first_name"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.last_name"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.company"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.contact_type_id"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.phone_number"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.reason_id"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.other", array(
            'label' => 'If other, please supply a reason'
        )); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.dated", array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'readonly' => 'readonly',
            'data-datepicker' => ''
        )); ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php echo $this->UiForm->end('Continue'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Ui->widgetContentEnd(); ?>
```

Controller

```
 public function add($id = null) {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Declination->create();
        if ($this->Declination->saveAll($this->data['Declination'])) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Declinations saved.', true));
            $this->redirect(array(
                'controller' => 'policies',
                'action' => 'view',
                $id
            ));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Declinations failed to save.', true));
        }
    }

    $reasons = $this->Declination->Reason->find('list');
    $contactTypes = $this->Declination->ContactType->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('id', 'reasons', 'contactTypes'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing UiForm is a custom helper of some sort. If it's similar to the Form helper, then it looks like an error in your create statement. It should be:

```
<?php echo $this->UiForm->create('Declination'); ?>
<?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.policy_id", array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => '$policy_id')); ?>
```

Comment: I tried but I had no luck. With that said, when I run my script $policy_id drops in my database instead of the desired id. I know this is something small but I cant put my finger on it.